# Nodejs module and require binding to global object

Tags: node.js, object, module, global, require

I noticed that when running from repl, **module** and **require** properties of GLOBAL node object are present ( console.log(GLOBAL) )
But when I examine GLOBAL object from inside application (again with console.log ) there is no module and require property of GLOBAL object. I thought that node will actually create those properties when application is present ( for example HTTP server ) ,cause that is the situation when we need to require external module ? Can someone explain please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every source file is wrapped into a function by node.js module helpers: see `NativeModule.wrapper`, `NativeModule.wrap` in [node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js). In your source file `exports`, `require`, `module`, `__filename`, `__dirname` are arguments to that function.

When running repl, `require` and others are referenced from repl context - see `REPLServer.prototype.createContext` in [repl.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L343)

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked node.js file, which can be found only in original node src/node.js source - so after reading everything is clear.